# Confused on the Proof Of Implicit Function Theorem Mean Value Step

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here is the following proof of the Implicit Function Theorem from Folland's Advanced Calculus:

> We may assume that $\partial_yF(a,b)>0$ (by replacing $F$ by $-F$ if
> necessary). Since $\partial_yF$ is continuous, it remains positive in
> some neighborhood of $(a, b)$, say for $|x-a|<r_1$ and $|y-b|<r_1$. On
> this set, $F(x,y)$ is a strictly increasing function of $y$ for each
> fixed $x$. In particular, since $F(a, b)=0$ we have $F(a, b+r_1)>0$
> and $F(a, b-r_1)<0$. The continuity of $F$ then implies that for some
> $r_0\leq r_1$ we have $F(x, b+r_1)>0$ and $F(x, b-r_1)<0$ for
> $|x-a|<r_0$.
>
> In short, for each $x$ in the ball $B=\{x: |x-a|<r_0\}$ we have $F(x,
>  b-r_1)<0, F(x, b+r_1)>0$ and $F(x,y)$ is strictly increasing as a
> function of $y$ for $|y-b|<r_1$. It follows from the intermediate
> value theorem that there is a unique $y$ for each $x\in B$ that
> satisfies $|y-b|<r_1$ and $F(x,y)=0$.
>
> Next we observe that the function $y=f(x)$ thus defined is continuous
> at $x=a$ in other words, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a
> $\delta>0$, where $y_0=f(x_0)$. For each such $x$ there is a unique
> $y$ such that $|y-y_0|<\epsilon$ and $F(x,y)$=0 and that $y=f(x)$ thus
> $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|y-y_0|<\epsilon$.
>
> Now that we know that $f$ is continuous on $B$, we can show that its
> partial derivatives $\partial_jf$ exist on $B$ and are given by
> (formula for IFT) which also shows they are continuous. Given $x\in B$
> and a small real number $h$ let $y=f(x)$ and \begin{align*}
> k=f(x+h)-f(x)\\ h=(0, \ldots, 0, h, 0, \ldots, 0) \end{align*} Then
> $y+k=f(x+h)$, so $F(x+h, y+k)=F(x,y)=0$. Hence by the mean value
> theorem, \begin{align*} 0&=F(x+h), y+k)-F(x,y)\\ &=h\partial_jF(x+th,
>  y+tk)+k\partial_yF(x+th, y+tk) \end{align*} for some $t\in (0, 1)$.
> Rearranging this equation gives \begin{align*}
>  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{k}{h}=-\frac{\partial_jF(x+th,
> > y+tk)}{\partial_yF(x+th, y+tk)} \end{align*} Now let $h\to 0$. Since
> $f$ is continuous we also have $k\to 0$ and then since $\partial_jF$
> and $\partial_yF$ are continuous and $\partial_yF\neq 0$ passage to
> the limit yields the Implicit Function Theorem.

At the step where it says $F(x+h, y+k)=F(x,y)=0$, I'm confused as to why that is true (I believe it because $y+k=f(x+h)$ and $F(x+h, f(x+h))=0$ but I may be mistaken)

Also, I am confused as to how the MVT (Mean Value Theorem) is applied to $0=F(x+h, y+k)-F(x,y)$ to get $h\partial_j(F(x+th, y+tk))+k\partial_y(F(x+th, y+tk))$ for $t\in (0, 1)$.

One last part I'm confused about is where it says how the continuity of $F$ implies that for some $r_0\leq r_1$ we have $F(x, b+r_1)>0$ and $F(x, b-r_1)<0$ for $|x-a|<r_0$. How does this follow from the continuity of $F$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello! Would you be willing to transcribe all of that, as it’s hard to read? A guide to MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: @MissMae Just transcribed all of it!

Comment: In first question your guess is correct. In second look at mvt for $n$ variables in Theorem 2.39, page 70, 2001.

Comment: @zkutch would it be the case that they are applying it using $\nabla f(c)=[\partial_jF(x+th, y+tk), \partial_yF(x+th, y+tk)]$ and $b-a=[h, k]^T$?

Comment: Yes. And third is property of continuous on open interval function, which have zero in interior point.

Comment: @zkutch I'm confused could you unpack that a bit? Also, in the gradient how come we incorporate $t$ into our equation? Is it because $(x+th, y+tk)$ is a point on the line $L$ between $(x+h, y+k)$ and $(x, y)$ for $t\in (0, 1)$?

Comment: Space segment $[(x,y), (x+h, y+k)]$ is set of points $\{(x+th, y+tk): t \in [0,1]\}$. In book this is $L$.

Comment: Right, what about the third point? You mentioned third is the property of continuity on open interval function, which have zero in interior point; how does this relate to being able to swap out $a$ for $x$ in the proof and claim $|x-a|<r_0$?

Comment: In a comment about the third question, I tried to condense the two properties into one sentence, but this may be more confusing than it helps, so I decide to write answer to third question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For third question, as 2 first I answered in comments. Let's start from place, that we have real function $F(\boldsymbol{x},y)$ continuous in some neighborhood of point $(\boldsymbol{a},b)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$, which is strictly increasing with respect to $y$ for each fixed $\boldsymbol{x}$. Assume this neighborhood is $\{(\boldsymbol{x},y):|\boldsymbol{x}-a|<r_1, |y-b|<r_1 \}$ for some $r_1>0$.

We know $F(\boldsymbol{a},b)=0$, so, based on a strict increase, $F(\boldsymbol{a},b-r_1)<0$ and $F(\boldsymbol{a},b+r_1)>0$.

Having, for example, $F(\boldsymbol{a},b-r_1)<0$, based on continuity with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$, we can find some neighborhood of $\boldsymbol{a}$, say $|\boldsymbol{x}-a|<r_0$ with $r_0<r_1$, where $F(\boldsymbol{x},b-r_1)<0$. This fact, for example, Michael Spivak - Calculus, 2008, page 119, Theorem 3.

Similarly, from $F(\boldsymbol{a},b+r_1)>0$ we obtain $F(\boldsymbol{x},b+r_1)>0$ for $|\boldsymbol{x}-a|<r_0$, having $r_0$ the same for both cases.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense; could you point me to a theorem which states that continuity with respect to a variable $x$ in a function induces a neighbourhood around some point? I think I am most confused about that line specifically. As I understand it, since $r_1>0$ then we can always find something smaller (like $r_1/2$).

Comment: Glad if I could be helpful. As for the theorem, either I misunderstand you or it has already been given - please take a look at the indicated book Michael Spivak - Calculus. True, there is the case of one real variable, but for the general case the result is the same and the proof given in the book is similar. As to $r_0$, then if existed from theorem one is more, then $r_1$ then, of course, we can take $r_0=r_1/2$.